# Why does partition algorithm not work in this case?

Tags: combinatorics

> Out of $8$ sailors on a boat, $3$ can work only on one particular side and $2$ only on the other side. Find the number of ways in which the sailors can be arranged on the boat.

I solved it in this way:

Let us assume sailors $S_1$,$S_2$,$S_3$ can work in the left side and sailors $S_4$ and $S_5$ can work in the right side. Let me represent partition of the remaining $3$ sailors into two groups by $|$. So, number of permutations of $S_6$$S_7$$S_8$$|$ is $4!$. Also, $S_1$,$S_2$,$S_3$ can be arranged in $3!$ and $S_4$,$S_5$ in $2!$ ways. So, total number of ways is $4!×3!×2!$. But the answer is $3×4!×4!$. Where is the mistake? Why doesn't the partition rule hold here?

**Edit**

I realised that it will not be simply $4!×3!×2!$ because I was excluding arrangements among all the members in one side. So, the actual answer (when it is not mentioned about the number of sailors in one side) is $$3!×5!+C(3,1)×4!×4!+C(3,2)×5!×3!+6!×2!$$ . I understood that because of the unstated assumption the answer is indeed $$C(3,1)×4!×4!$$.

N.B. This question has already been asked. Mine is not a duplicate because I am not asking for a solution, rather I want to know why partition doesn't hold good here.

Comment: The unwritten underlying (more nautical than mathematical) assumption seems to be that the 8 sailors have to be distributed equally among the two sides. There are $3$ ways to pick the one ambidextrous sailor for the "one" side; the other two must go to the "other" side. Now you can permute the four sailors within each side, i..e, $4!$ for one side and $4!$ for the other.

Comment: As Hagen points out, [some assumptions are missing from your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805015#comment1663823_805015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Hagen von Eitzen's excellent comment. The reason the partition rule doesn't work here is that the 'ambidextrous' sailors are part of groups on the left or right of the boat, but can take *any* position within the side they are on. So the one ambidextrous sailor on the left could in position 1, 2, 3, or 4. This is what the partition rule count misses.